# Android splash screen dynamic icon

Tags: android, splash-screen

In our app we have several launcher icons. We do it via activity-alias. Code in Manifest looks like below. The problem is that I can't show different splash screen logos. Splash screen style is used only from `<activity>` tag. The one in `<activity-alias>` tag is ignored.

```
<activity
            android:name=".modules.launcher.LauncherActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.MainLauncherStyle" />
<activity-alias
            android:name="${applicationId}.MainLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_main"
            android:label="@string/App_Name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.MainLauncherStyle"
            android:targetActivity=".modules.launcher.LauncherActivity">
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name="${applicationId}.DarkLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_dark"
            android:label="@string/App_Name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.DarkLauncherStyle"
            android:targetActivity=".modules.launcher.LauncherActivity">
        </activity-alias>
```

Comment: Currently I decided to remove splash icon from splash screen style for SDK 31. Android with SDK 31 and greater will show different icons which is taken from manifest `<activity-alias>`. Older SDK will use single splash screen icon that is indicated in style.